# Google API BlackList

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

our company is developing some services which use Google's ADMIN SDK apis.
Our problem is that when we call the apis endpoints it starts to say "403 insufficient permissions".
If we change the server with another IP then the service works again without any trouble.

Since we need to use the IP where we get "insufficient permissions" is it possibile that this is blackisted? And if so is it possibile
to whitelist them?
We havn't found any answer to this question in the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Antonio

Answer (score 1):

`Insufficient permissions` does not mean you have been black listed.  It means that you are trying to execute a method against the API that you haven't been authenticated for.

You specify what access you need by the [scope](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing) command in your authentication process.   There are a large number of scopes.

Lets say I authenticate my user with

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly Scope
>   for only retrieving group member roles and information.

This will only give me read-only access to the group member directory.

What happens if I try and do [Users: insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert) the documentation states that I need the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user`.  So if I try and insert a user when I only have read only access I am going to get

> 403 insufficient permissions

Comment: let me explain my problem in more detail: using the same credentials I have no problem calling the API from any machine on our local network; however I get the permission error I just showed you if I call the API (using the same service account credentials) for PUT and POST requests from any EC2 inside our VPC on Amazon Web Services. I can call any API endpoint which uses GET requests.

Comment: I think you should update your question and add some code